# Equivalent for Time Machine that writes to NTFS disks

Tags: software-rec, ntfs, osx-lion, time-machine

I'm looking for some OS X Lion software that can periodically backup certain folders.

I can't use Time Machine because the storage disk is NTFS and I'm using Paragon to r/w on it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81401/discussion-on-question-by-pablo-equivalent-for-time-machine-that-writes-to-ntfs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not looking for any fancy features that NTFS does not have, I'd basically go with [**Carbon Copy Cloner**](http://www.bombich.com/).

Its features include:

- Incremental backup of files and folders to external hard drives, network or disk images
- Scheduled backups (hourly, weekly, etc.)

Given a proper NTFS driver, it should work with NTFS drives.

As Lukasa pointed out, adding a `cron` job that runs [**`rsync`**](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) on a regular basis would also do the trick, albeit with a less user-friendly approach due to lacking GUI.

Comment: CCC is not free.

Comment: It used to be though. I removed the "free" part.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from [an Ask Different answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57082/8546) to **Enabling Time Machine for a USB HDD with NTFS**:

---

## Backup to NTFS

If you wish to use Time Machine in Lion or greater with an NTFS volume – and if you have a  write-enabled driver for NTFS:

- with [tmutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man8/tmutil.8.html) you can configure Time Machine to back up to a sparse bundle disk image, the .sparsebundle stored on NTFS.

In some situations you may find that Time Machine simply offers to use an NTFS volume. This may occur if, say, a write-enabled driver for NTFS is installed *before* a physical disk with NTFS is introduced to OS X.

## Restore from NTFS

OS X can read NTFS, and so should be able to restore from a .sparsebundle in this environment.

Whether Recovery OS is similarly prepared to read from NTFS and restore, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

[Time Machine can backup to an NTFS drive](http://www.cafe-encounter.net/p1847/use-a-windows-ntfs-or-linux-or-other-formatted-disk-for-apple-time-machine-backups) using a sparsebundle but there's a bit of work involved. If you've already got a read-write driver like Paragon then your remaining steps are:

- Create the sparsebundle diskimage
- Create the 'magic' Time Machine preferences file, containing the UUID of your machine, and save it in the sparsebundle's Package Contents
- Mount the sparsebundle image by doubling-clicking in Finder
- Tell Time Machine to use it.

The blog post contains a script to do the fiddly bits, especially getting your UUID and creating the preferences file, and to set it as Time Machine backup destination.